# Read the first word on a specific line from a text file using batch script then feed into an for statement

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am in the process of writing a health check script for the devices I manage.
Given below is the output is the command which lists every device I manage.
For every listing of device I want to run certain health check commands and check status for each device. The format of the input is listed below.
I want to select the first word which will be the serial number of the box.
As these devices are managed from windows box, need to create batch file.

==================================================================

C:\Documents and Settings\server>symcfg list

```
                            S Y M M E T R I X

                                   Mcode    Cache      Num Phys  Num Symm
SymmID       Attachment  Model     Version  Size (MB)  Devices   Devices

000192xxxxxx Local       VMAX-1    5876      24064         9     1055
000192xxxxxx Local       VMAX-1    5876      12032        7      379
000192xxxxxx Local       VMAX-1    5876      24064         9      661
000192xxxxxx Local       VMAX20K   5876      36096        17      258
```

=============================================================================

I want to select every serial number from the column "SymmID" only and then pass every serial number to a for loop which will run some commands for health checking.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to skip the first 5 header lines and process the rest:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=5" %%a in ('symcfg list') do echo %%a
```

The first token separated by space (default behaviour) is assigned to %%a.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    for /f %%a in (
        'symcfg list ^| findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]"'
    ) do (
        echo %%a
    )

    endlocal
```

Execute the command, filter the lines to retrieve only those containing required data (lines starting with a number in the included sample). `for` command will tokenize the string using spaces (default behaviour), retrieving the first token in the line.

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off
set "file=C:\Documents and Settings\server>symcfg list"
set /A i=0

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
set /A i+=1
call echo %%i%%
call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
call set n=%%i%%
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do call echo %%array[%%i]%%
```

Comment: As posted this isn't going to work Robert.   Even if the symcfg command is fixed, it's not going to exclude unwanted lines or parse the wanted lines correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Use a for loop .. somethin like this

@echo off

For /f %%a in (filename.extension) do (

Echo %%a

)

That would output the first token in every possible line in the file...

Note replace filename.extension with the appropriate file 
For this code to work you have to 
Place the batch file in  the directory containing the file symcfg list and run it